# Generating Selection List with Cosmos DocumentDB

Tags: node.js, azure-cosmosdb

I am looking to generate a selection list with data from a Cosmos documentDB, each list will be independent of each other.  I am currently only able to generate one list and the second list is a replica of the first, it won't read both.  Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

App.js

```
const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient
 const config = require('./config')
 const TaskList = require('./routes/tasklist')
 const TaskDao = require('./models/taskDao')



 const express = require('express')
 const path = require('path')
 const logger = require('morgan')
 const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

 const app = express()

 // view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
 app.set('view engine', 'jade')

 // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
 //app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
 app.use(logger('dev'))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
 app.use(cookieParser())
 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

 //Todo App:
 const cosmosClient = new CosmosClient({
   endpoint: config.host,
   key: config.authKey
 })
 const taskDao = new TaskDao(cosmosClient, config.databaseId, config.containerId)
 const taskDao2 = new TaskDao(cosmosClient, config.databaseId2, config.containerId2)
 const taskList = new TaskList(taskDao,taskDao2)


 taskDao
   .init(err => {
     console.error(err)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err)
     console.error(
       'Shutting down because there was an error settinig up the database.'
     )
     process.exit(1)
   })

   taskDao2
   .init(err => {
     console.error(err)
   })
   .catch(err => {
     console.error(err)
     console.error(
       'Shutting down because there was an error settinig up the database.'
     )
     process.exit(1)
   })



 app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showClosurePlanList(req, res).catch(next))
 app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showTestList2(req, res).catch(next))
 app.post('/addtask', (req, res, next) => taskList.addTask(req, res).catch(next))

 app.set('view engine', 'jade')


 // catch 404 and forward to error handler
 app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   const err = new Error('Not Found')
   err.status = 404
   next(err)
 })

 // error handler
 app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
   // set locals, only providing error in development
   res.locals.message = err.message
   res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

   // render the error page
   res.status(err.status || 500)
   res.render('error')
 })

 module.exports = app
```

taskDao.js

```
// @ts-check
 const CosmosClient = require('@azure/cosmos').CosmosClient
 const debug = require('debug')('todo:taskDao')

 // For simplicity we'll set a constant partition key
 const partitionKey = undefined
 class TaskDao {
   /**
    * Manages reading, adding, and updating Tasks in Cosmos DB
    * @param {CosmosClient} cosmosClient
    * @param {string} databaseId
    * @param {string} containerId
    */
   constructor(cosmosClient, databaseId, containerId) {
     this.client = cosmosClient
     this.databaseId = databaseId
     this.collectionId = containerId

     this.database = null
     this.container = null
   }

   async init() {
     debug('Setting up the database...')
     const dbResponse = await this.client.databases.createIfNotExists({
       id: this.databaseId
     })
     this.database = dbResponse.database
     debug('Setting up the database...done!')
     debug('Setting up the container...')
     const coResponse = await this.database.containers.createIfNotExists({
       id: this.collectionId
     })
     this.container = coResponse.container
     debug('Setting up the container...done!')
   }

   async find(querySpec, querySpec2) {
     debug('Querying for items from the database')
     if (!this.container) {
       throw new Error('Collection is not initialized.')
     }
     const { resources } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec,querySpec2).fetchAll()
     return resources

   }




   async addItem(item) {
     debug('Adding an item to the database')
     item.date = Date.now()
     item.completed = false
     const { resource: doc } = await this.container.items.create(item)
     return doc
   }

   async getItem(itemId) {
     debug('Getting an item from the database')
     const { resource } = await this.container.item(itemId, partitionKey).read()
     return resource
   }
 }

 module.exports = TaskDao
```

tasklist.js

```
const TaskDao = require("../models/taskDao");

 class TaskList {
   /**
    * Handles the various APIs for displaying and managing tasks
    * @param {TaskDao} taskDao
    */
   constructor(taskDao,taskDao2) {
     this.taskDao = taskDao;
     this.taskDao2 = taskDao2;
   }

   async showClosurePlanList(req, res) {
    const querySpec = {
      query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.ClosurePlanList=@ClosurePlanList",
      parameters: [
        {
          name: "@ClosurePlanList",
          value: "yes"
        }
      ]

    };

     const items = await this.taskDao2.find(querySpec);
     res.render("index", {
       title: "Form",
       tasks: items
     });

   }


    async showTestList2(req, res) {
     const querySpec2 = {
       query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.completed=@completed",
        parameters: [
          {
            name: "@completed",
            value: true
         }
       ]
     };

      const items2 = await this.taskDao.find(querySpec2);
      res.render("index", {
        title: "Form",
        tasks: items2
      });

    }

   async addTask(req, res) {
     const item = req.body;

     await this.taskDao.addItem(item);

     res.redirect("/");
   }


 }

 module.exports = TaskList;
```

[image]

[image]

So I have one list - Closure Plan List, that currently looks at ClosurePlanList DocumentDB (which is perfect).

How do I get the second list - Test List 2, to look at the TestList2 DocumentDB?

I attempted to add do something like this but it is only reading one app.get at a time.  I'm thinking this is where my issue is.  Which ever app.get is on top seems to be the only one that is read.

```
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showClosurePlanList(req, res).catch(next))
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => taskList.showTestList2(req, res).catch(next))
```

```
async find(querySpec, querySpec2) {
     debug('Querying for items from the database')
     if (!this.container) {
       throw new Error('Collection is not initialized.')
     }
     const { resources } = await this.container.items.query(querySpec,querySpec2).fetchAll()
     return resources

   }
```

```
   async showTestList2(req, res) {
     const querySpec2 = {
       query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.completed=@completed",
        parameters: [
          {
            name: "@completed",
            value: true
         }
       ]
     };

      const items2 = await this.taskDao.find(querySpec2);
      res.render("index", {
        title: "Form",
        tasks: items2
      });

    }
```

Example from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-nodejs-application#_Toc395783181

Comment: So you just want to query data from TestList2 DocumentDB in this nodejs project? May I know what is find(querySpec, querySpec2) function for?

Comment: Yes, I would like each drop down selection list to correspond to a different DocumentDB. I am looking to have 5 DocumentDB and 5 drop down selection list. So each list would have a different query. Is this possible?  That function was just me testing it out, it didn’t work properly.  Do you want me to draw out what I’m looking to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get data and show them in : `http://localhost:3000` , you should modify both `views/index.jade` and `showTasks` function in `routes/tasklist.js`.

I implemented a simple demo for you. Firstly, go to `routes/tasklist.js`, replace `showTasks` function with code below :

```
   async showTasks(req, res) {
     const querySpec = {
       query: "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.completed=@completed",
       parameters: [
         {
           name: "@completed",
           value: false
         }
       ]
     };

     const items = await this.taskDao.find(querySpec);
     const itemsFromCollection1 = await this.taskDao.find("SELECT * FROM r");
     const itemsFromCollection2 = await this.taskDao2.find("SELECT * FROM r");
     res.render("index", {
       title: "My ToDo List ",
       tasks: items,
       list1 : itemsFromCollection1,
       list2 : itemsFromCollection2
     });
   }
```

[image]

Go to `views/index.jade` , append the code below to show your list1 and list2 data:

```
 label data from collection1 
 select(id="demo1")
    -for(var i = 0;i<list1.length;i++){
    option(value="#{i}") #{list1[i].name}
    -}
  
  label data from collection2
  select(id="demo2")
    -for(var i = 0;i<list2.length;i++){
    option(value="#{i}") #{list2[i].name}
    -}
```

With steps are done, you can run the project and test it :

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps . Pls mark it as an answer if it is helpful for you . If you have any further questions, pls post a new query and let me know the link .

Comment: Is it possible to get it to display both list on the same page?  Currently I have to navigate to http://localhost:3000 to see the data on one list and then go to http://localhost:3000/list2 to see the second set of data

Comment: Hi @williswin , of course it is possible . I have updated my answer.